# What is the difference between printf("\ %d ",&t); and printf("%d ",t);

Tags: c, io, printf

I was trying some C codes in Dev C++ and Visual C++.

For Example:

```
int t =6;
printf("\nt = %d ",&t);
```

The output is :

```
t = 2358848
```

why is it so ? How can I get the value of t?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&t` gives you the [*address of*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p3) `t` , not its value.

To print the value do:

```
printf("\nt = %d ", t);
```

Answer (score 2):

The & is known as a unary, and it gives you the address of a variable. This gets confusing because when you use scanf, it wants an address to store the user input so it has you use a unary. But when printing, it wants the value to display it on screen, it doesn't care what its address is.

Example:

```
int t = 0;
scanf("%d", &t); // This saves what the user inputs to the memory location of t
printf("\n %d", t); // This prints the value the user input
```

Alternatively, if you actually want to see what an address is:

```
printf("\n %p", &t); // This displays a memory location properly formatted.
```

Comment: The `p` conversion specifier is defined for `void`-pointers only. So it should be `printf("\n %p", (void*) &t);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `printf("\nt = %d ", t);`

You are trying to print address of the `t` variable.